# Resultado variável com IDHTTP

Tags: delphi

preciso obter o resultado de um link e colocar em um memo. Vou explicar melhor em exemplos:

Vou acessar o link: `http://www.xxx.com.br/teste.php?Teste` (esse endereço vai me retornar a palavra OK.

É possível acessar esse esse endereço via idHTTP, pegar esse resultado e colocar em um Memo ? Sei que via WININET é possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim.

Basta utilizar o método [`Get`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/HTTP_Get_%28Delphi%29) do `IdHttp`, assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 Const
   LINK = 'http://www.xxx.com.br/teste.php?Teste';
begin
   IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
   IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';

   Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(LINK);
end;
```

Comment: Esse método como está retorna o código fonte da página. Se *(e somente se)* o OP estiver utilizando a última versão do indy, ele poderia obter o que solicitou com o comando `http.Get(LINK, nil);`, porém para que o método funcione em versões mais antigas do indy, acho melhor utilizar o método head.

Comment: @Sunstreaker, não deu certo, ele da erro Forbiden, o endereço para TESTE verdadeiro é esse: http://www.escritoriocontatos.com.br/teste.php?LETRA

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, ele deu erro de Forbiden no seu também. Veja o endereço http://www.escritoriocontatos.com.br/teste.php?LETRA

Comment: @user7605 apenas a carater de teste, retire temporariamente seu htaccess da pasta / e tente novamente.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, acabei de retirar e testei de novo, ele aparece no showmessage o codigo 403. Mais já conferi tudo, ta tudo certo....

Comment: @Sunstreaker o método ainda pega o "exibir codigo fonte" para o Indy9. Sobre a leitura, sensacional workaround!

Comment: Perfeito @Sunstreaker, obrigado!

Comment: @Sunstreaker, desse jeito ai da pra fazer algum teste de quando o link cair ele gerar uma mensagem, tipo LINK FORA DO AR!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método HEAD, lembrando que caso a resposta não seja 200 (ok), a rotina vai cair em exceção e esta deve ser tratada.

Segue exemplo conforme o solicitado na pergunta:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  http : TIdHttp;
  url : string;
  codigo : integer;
begin
  url := 'http://www.xxx.com.br/teste.php?Teste';
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      http.Head(url);
      codigo := http.ResponseCode;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        codigo := http.ResponseCode;
    end;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(codigo));
  finally
    http.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Lembrando que para fazer surgir a palavra OK, basta fazer uso de um case na variável código. Para isso, segue [lista de códigos de resposta HTTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aLista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#Lista_de_c.C3.B3digos_de_status_HTTP)